# Windows IoT I2C repeated start

Tags: iot, i2c, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to use a RPi2B with Windows IoT to communicate with a GE power supply via I2C. I can do simple reads and writes OK, but anything involving a repeated start is unreliable.  Since the power supply's PMBus command set is dominated by WriteRead I2C transactions (which require repeated starts), most of my attempts to read from specific registers fail... but occasionally it works as expected.  Here is the relevant code...

```csharp
public void Read_Firmware_Rev()
        {
            Windows.Devices.I2c.I2cTransferResult Temp;
            byte[] ReadBuffer = new byte[8];
            var CommandBuffer = new byte[1] { Firmware_Rev };        
            Temp = _I2C.WriteReadPartial(CommandBuffer, ReadBuffer);
           
             if (Temp.Status == I2cTransferStatus.FullTransfer)
            {
                String S = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ReadBuffer);
                Debug.WriteLine(S);
            }
             else Debug.Write("-");
        }
```

[image]
The top image is the most common result; the bottom is rare success.  A successful transactions has a clock stretch (by whom?) after the first byte as well as a repeated start after the command byte 0xD5.

The power supply's documentation says that it accepts repeated starts and can stretch the clock.  It's not a speed problem.... I am querying the power supply only 1/sec at 100kHz.
Can anyone suggest why this behavior are occurring?

Comment: Are you sure this is on an Rpi2b? As far as I know, Windows IOT core is only supported on the Rpi3b. Also, please specify exactly which library you are using.

Comment: Yes, you're right RPi3b.  Running Ver 10.0.17763.107

Comment: What library are you using for the I2C transfer?

Comment: Windows.Devices.I2c;, the standard .NET library for UWP C# in Windows IoT.  I think that's what you are asking.

Comment: I think that library is very old. Try `System.Device.Gpio` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion..  System.Device.I2c is part of the System.Device.Gpio package (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.i2c.i2cdevice?view=iot-dotnet-2.1)  I was hoping to avoid bit-banging GPIO pins, using the Microsoft library instead.  Maybe that won't get me where I need to go.

Comment: Why bit-banging? Of course I meant to use `System.Device.I2c` (or rather `System.Device.I2cDevice`). `System.Device.Gpio` is the name of the nuget package.

Comment: I refactored my code to use the System.Device.I2cDevice library but the behavior remained about the same:  successful WriteRead <10% of the time.  Both libraries employ repeated starts but something (in my hardware, I presume) is eating them.

Comment: I have done many tests with different I2C devices and never observed this behavior. I did see communication errors, but maybe every 10000'th transaction failed, nothing to worry about. Have you the possibility to test with a different I2C device?

Comment: The power supply in question (CP3500AC54) has a floating ground for its I2C interface.  Consequently. I have a ISO1640 galvanic isolator between the RPi and the power supply.  The isolator appears to faithfully pass the I2C signals but perhaps its presence is compromising the RPi master's repeat start condition.

Comment: I can't try another I2C slave, but perhaps another RPi is available.

Comment: That sounds like a possibility. Level shifters and translators for I2C are quite sensitive and must be explicitly suitable for bidirectional communication. If you suspect problems with the galvanic isolator, you might get help at electronics.se

Comment: I think that I found the problem.  The RPi does not react to clock stretching properly.  If a Repeated Start occurs when the clock is stretched, the RPi never sees it and WriteRead transactions are corrupted..  Slave devices that do not use clock stretching perform properly, but unfortunately my power supply clock-stretches often.  see https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=13771&start=25 and http://www.advamation.com/knowhow/raspberrypi/rpi-i2c-bug.html .  It appears that this is a permanent bug.  Do not use RPi with I2C devices that employ clock stretching.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi 2b is unable to execute an I2C repeated Start and consequently cannot do a WriteRead sequence.  A hardware solution is the NXP SC18IS604 chip which translates SPI to I2C.  RPi talks to the SC18IS604 via SPI and SC18IS604 then talks to the external device with I2C. It works well for me.  https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SC18IS604.pdf